# Reusable react-hook-form useFieldArray component in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-hook-form

I am making a reusable, dynamic form component using react-hook-form's useFieldArray hook and I am having problems correctly adding the type for `field`.

To set-up the form I have added a type and some defaultValues:

```
export type NamesArray = { name: string; required: boolean }[];

export type FormValues = { randomFormValue: string; namesArray: NamesArray };

const defaultValues = {
  namesArray: [{ name: "Me", required: true }]
};
```

Now, when I use my reusable form component, `<NamesForm />` it should always know to use the `namesArray` part of the form for that component such that I should be able to do:

```
type Props<T> = {
  control: Control<T>;
  register: UseFormRegister<T>;
};

export function NamesForm<T extends NamesArray>({
  control,
  register
}: Props<T>) {
  const { fields, append } = useFieldArray<T, "namesArray", "id">({
    control,
    name: "namesArray"
  });

  return (
    <>
      {fields.map((field, index) => {
        return field.required && <input {...register(`namesArray.${index}.name` as const)} />;
      })}

      <button type="button" onClick={() => append({})}>
        Append
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Where, in order to make the component reusable, I have used generic props.

My problem is that even though I have explicitly said that my generic `T` should contain a `namesArray`, TS can't seem to pick that up and gives me the error:

> Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'ArrayPath'.

And it is not enough for me to not define the type of `field` because I would like to use `field`'s properties such as `required`.

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-field-array-forked-vooe9w?file=/src/NamesForm.tsx:139-214

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for the problem? I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your generic field values `T` should extend an object containing `namesArray`, not an array.

```
type Name = {
  name: string;
  required: boolean;
};
type FormValuesWithNamesArray = {
  namesArray: Name[];
};
export function NamesForm<T extends FormValuesWithNamesArray>
```

But even with this change the error persist. What did work for me is to remove the generic:

```
export type = Name {
  name: string;
  required: boolean;
}
export type FormValuesWithNamesArray = {
  namesArray: Name[];
  [key: string]: any;
}
type Props = {
  control: Control<FormValuesWithNamesArray>;
  register: UseFormRegister<FormValuesWithNamesArray>;
};

export function NamesForm({ control, register }: Props) {
  const { fields, append } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "namesArray",
  });

  return (
    <>
      {fields.map((field, index) => {
        return (
          field.required && (
            <input {...register(`namesArray.${index}.name` as const)} />
          )
        );
      })}

      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => append({ name: "", required: false })}
      >
        Append
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```